# @@TRANCOUNT misbehaving

Tags: sql-server, transactions

Does the INSERT INTO @table EXEC(@sql) statement create an implict transaction ? In my @sql code I've got a test to check that a stored procedure is running within a transaction and it appears that the @@TRANCOUNT increments by 1 when I call the query. Is there anyway to disable this type of functionality ?

I've got no explicit transactions created in my calling code and the table that the output of the stored procedure is output into is already pre-defined as a table variable declare @response table(r xml).

It only matters for the test harness we're creating but it means that the transaction count at the point I check in the child procedure has gone up to 1 so my check in there fails.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188317(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Every DML statement *has* to be inside a transaction.

Comment: At the point that I'm at in the code though, I've not done the insert therefore I don't expect there to be a transaction created

Comment: The `INSERT` statement has started. Your code may not have generated any rows yet, but that doesn't mean that the whole statement hasn't started, and the statement requires a transaction.